# Json no Jquery retorna undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Apesar de ter olhado todas as varias perguntas sobre isso, não consigo fazer o meu json funcionar, o código esta assim:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?= base_url('login/Pesquisar'); ?>',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $("#formulario_pesquisa").serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data))
        alert(Object.keys(data));
        alert(data.email);
    }
});
```

Os resultados são:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data)) >>> {"cnpj ":"68.207.717/0001-42","email ":"teste.teste@email.com","Logado":true)

alert(Object.keys(data)); >> cnpj ,email ,Logado

alert(data.email); >> undefined
```

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso??

Comment: o problema deve ser isso mesmo que o gabriel disse. Só um para constar tambem caso voce não tenha como mudar o servidor pode pegar o valor assim `data['email ']`note que tem um espaco depois do email

Comment: Verdade, poderia funcionar desta forma também, mas eu tive como mudar sim, foi um vacilo mesmo rsrs. Muito Obrigado o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando utilizado o JSON.stringfy() ele está escrevendo {"email ":"valor"}, veja que existe um espaço em branco após a chave "email". Verifique se o código que retorna o JSON está montando ele corretamente.

Veja um exemplo:

Este primeiro ira retornar *undefined* pois a chave está definida como "email ".

```
var json = {"email ":"teste.teste@email.com"};
console.log(json.email) <= undefined
```

Já este retornará o conteúdo "teste.teste@email.com"

```
var json = {"email":"teste.teste@email.com"};
console.log(json.email) <= teste.teste@email.com
```

Comment: Nossa, que vacilo, muito obrigado